# Sending HTML email from spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making some improvements to a tutorial. The code sends an email from a Google spreadsheet and take the subject there and marks when the email has been sent, I'm trying to make the message in html.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = 'Correo Enviado';
 //non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.



function sendEmails2() {

  var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Correo_HTML').evaluate();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,7).getValue(); // Number of rows 

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3);

  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; 
    var message = templ.getContent();
    var emailSent = row[3]; 

    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = row[2];

      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 4).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);

      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted

      SpreadsheetApp.flush();

      }
    }
  }
```

and I'm writing the HTML code in another window, is super simple but I don't know where could be the trouble

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2> Test 2</h2>
    <p>
    Hello World
    </p>
    <p><strong> learning </strong></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

So how can I get the message in the email with the format in the HTML code?

Comment: There seems to be a version of the `MailApp.sendEmail` function ([MailApp.sendEmail(to, replyTo, subject, body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))) that expects **plain text** for the email body.

Comment: Try this: `MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message,{htmlBody:'<h2> Test 2</h2><p>Hello World</p><p><strong> learning </strong></p>'});` [sendEmail with options](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))

Comment: It works, Thank you, I will keep going with some little improvements more!